# Firebase Javascript: Creating a numeric Index on File Upload to Firebase Realtime

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a little app that allows me to upload files, one at a time, to firebase storage. In the process it creates a database reference where it stores the user that uploaded it, the downlodurl etc.

However I have hit an issue as I want to serve back to the user their uploads at random, which is not something easily done by firebase DB at the moment (it would seem - happy to be proven wrong though!!) so I was wondering if it was possible on upload to create a numeric index field that auto increments after every upload?

Would it be as simple as querying the database pulling the max value for the current index and then +1 to it?

Below is the (fairly boilerplate) database referencing bit of the code where I would want to add the index number:

```
        var imagekey = firebase.database().ref('images/').push().key;
        var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
        var updates = {};
        var postData = {
            url: downloadURL,
            index: 
            user: user.uid
        };            
        updates ['/images/'+imagekey] = postData;
        firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
      });
```

Ok thanks to the help of Frank below I was able to write the following function to create a data base reference of "index" and increase it by one on every single upload:

```
 var indexRef = firebase.database().ref('index');
 indexRef.transaction(function(currentRank) {
 return currentRank + 1;
 });
```

However it did have an incredibly odd effect when inserted into my upload function - the upload would continue to work, the file would appear in storage - but only the index database reference would be written, all other information would be lost and I would get an incredibly complex error in the console. Here is the updated code - any ideas as to what I may have done incorrectly?

```
      function complete(){

        //write a database reference
        var indexRef = firebase.database().ref('index');
        indexRef.transaction(function(currentRank) {
        return currentRank + 1;
        });
        var imagekey = firebase.database().ref('images/').push().key;
        var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
        var updates = {};
        var postData = {
            url: downloadURL,
            score: 1500,
            index: indexRef,
            user: user.uid
        };            
        updates ['/images/'+imagekey] = postData;
        firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a value to the database, based on a value that is currently in the database, you'll [use transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

The trickiest bit with transactions is that they work on a single location in the database. With the data model you propose, you'd be reading from one post (highest index so far) to then write to another one. That would mean that you need a transaction on the entire `images` node, which is a huge problem for scalability.

What you'll likely want to do is keep a "highest used counter value" somewhere in a single spot and then "claim next value and write updated value" on that in a transaction. That means read-and-update the counter in a transaction, and then write the image with the index you just claimed.

Comment: Thanks for the help - just to make sure I've got this correct in my head, I would maintain this script as is but nest another variable above postData that would have a transaction function to determine the index to be added and claim that value in the DB, which I would then call as the index value in the postData ={} below? (If what I've said has made sense haha)

Comment: Yup. That's also pretty much what RDBMSs do when you mark a column as auto-increment.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much for the advice.... I'm going to attempt this when I get home from work today, so I might be bothering you again when I can't make it work right! But fingers crossed it all goes smoothly!

Comment: I've hit an error - I've updated the question to explain the issue, it's probably something obvious that I can't see but judging by the error I've clearly just missed something in the index bit in post data. I've tried both Index.value and index. 

Though typing this now would I not need to write another database reference, and just pull the index number from there? As the function would have already updated this - I'm gonna try this now